# Calculate three angle of triangle using three sides

Tags: c++

I want to find three angle of a Triangle using Given three sides but it gives me 'nan' value.

I have tried law of cosines to find the angles but it ain't working. It gives 'nan' value.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double findDegree(double setDegree)
{
    return setDegree * M_PI / 180;
}
double findRadian(double setRadian)
{
    return acos(setRadian);
}
int main()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Give three sides of the triangle: ";
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    double angleA, angleB, angleC, getRadian, getDegree;
    angleA = ((b * b) + (c * c) - (a * a)) / 2 * b * c;
    angleB = ((a * a) + (c * c) - (b * b)) / 2 * a * c;
    angleC = ((a * a) + (b * b) - (c * c)) / 2 * a * b;
    // A
    getRadian = findRadian(angleA);
    getDegree = findDegree(getRadian);
    angleA = getDegree;
    // B
    getRadian = findRadian(angleB);
    getDegree = findDegree(getRadian);
    angleB = getDegree;
    // A
    getRadian = findRadian(angleC);
    getDegree = findDegree(getRadian);
    angleC = getDegree;

    cout << "Angle A is: " << angleA << endl;
    cout << "Angle B is: " << angleB << endl;
    cout << "Angle C is: " << angleC << endl;
}
```

Comment: `a`,`b` and `c` are integers, they use integer arithmetics. Why are they no `double` ?

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: At the very least use `2.0` instead of `2` in the angle formulas.

Comment: You could also test the validity of the input: 1. positive numbers 2. The max value is less than the sum of the two others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radian to degrees is "rad * 180 / pi", you're doing it the other way around in `findDegree`. Why are you doing it anyway?

You also need to put the denominator in parenthesis, for example:

```
    angleA = ((b * b) + (c * c) - (a * a)) / (2 * b * c);
```

`a`,  `b`, `c` should be `double` probably, as well.

Answer (score 1):

here is second main mistake:

```
double findDegree(double setDegree)
{
    return setDegree * M_PI / 180;
}
```

Change to:

```
double findDegree(double setDegree)
{
    return setDegree * 180 / M_PI;
}
```